# could not create unique index, key is duplicated django postgres

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I got following user table with same  uuid . I want this uuid to be unique . but while changing the uuid from my user model with unique=True and editable=False
While executing migrate command , I am getting "psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: could not create unique index" error with Key (hnid)=(8c0bc4a2-165a-47d5-8084-8b87600c7fe8) is duplicated.

## my models.py

hnid = models.UUIDField("HNID", default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, null=True, unique=True,editable=False)

Note: I am using postgres
How can I solve this issue
[image]

Comment: You will have to change the duplicate values first or delete those entries.

Comment: how can i do that ? sorry I am new to this

Comment: Please add your models to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your definition of hnid. You can use directly `primary_key=True`.

```
hnid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid_lib.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
```

`primary_key=True` implies `null=False` and `unique=True` and is readonly. Only one primary key is allowed on an object according to the doc.
`blank=True` is not a good idea : you do not want to have a blank primary key on your object. Plus, it would not work with `unique=True`.

About the migration, Django gives a good example on their documention : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields
And it works well !